# Mongoose Aggregation giving field name a name from value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

So I am currently trying to get data out of a collection and group it by year and type,

```
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            year: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y", date: "$date" } },
            typeId: "$type",
          },
          count: { $sum: 1 },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          "$_id.year": {
            $push: {
              _id: "$_id.typeId",
              typeCount: "$count",
            },
          },
        },
      },
```

Anyway I am getting an error for using `$` in my field name at the project because I want to order the result as an array of key values:

```
years[year]: {
   count: num,
   typeId: String
}
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: I think, you still need to group the second time with the `year` value from he first grouping. Then you can work with that result to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$toString` to convert year from number type to string type, because below operation requires it as string type
- `$arrayToObject` convert key-value array of object to an object format

```
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      years: {
        $arrayToObject: [
          [
            {
              k: { $toString: "$_id.year" },
              v: {
                typeId: "$_id.typeId",
                count: "$count"
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LdPMaC1ZTMx)

Comment: Thank you so much man I am actually pretty new with Aggregation and this is new to me so thanks a lot!